# StarCraft 2 keyboard shortcut to select hatchery

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-zerg, keyboard

Is there a keyboard shortcut to select and center view to the Command Center/Hatchery/Nexus? Playing as Zerg, I tried pressing <kbd>H</kbd> but it doesn't select the hatchery.

I'm looking for a keyboard shortcut that will select and center view even if the current view is elsewhere on the map (something similar to pressing space).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

<kbd>Backspace</kbd> will allow you to cycle through your Command Centers/Nexuses/Hatcheries.  You can also set a building to a group -- for instance, I set my main base's command center to <kbd>0</kbd>, my first expansion to <kbd>9</kbd>, etc.  That might be useful or not for you, but it helps me get around the map faster than hitting <kbd>Backspace</kbd> several times.

Comment: nice catch, I've been binding my Hatch to 5 for so long I had actually forgotten this.

Comment: Backspace is too far right, but I guess I can assign it to the 0, 1 or 2 keys.

Comment: Interesting, I would never use a control group past 6. It actually hurts to press Ctrl + 0 with the left hand.